# Why is this python script not working?

Tags: python, modeling, scripting

```
import bmesh
bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.edit_object.data).faces[1].select=True
```

It says python script fail
What should I do ?

Comment: What would you like to obtain?

Comment: The mesh object needs to be (a mesh, and) in edit mode (meshobject == context.edit_object) to use `bmesh.from_edit_mesh(...)`  Use this if you are going to make an edit mode tool.  A call to bmesh.update_edit_mesh(...)` will show your changes "live".   Otherwise use `bm = bmesh.new()` and load the mesh with `bm.from_mesh(...)`.  Oh and `import bpy`  too, what exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

This is how to create a new object and add the vertices in the *verts* list:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

verts = [(1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)]  # 2 verts made with XYZ coords
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("mesh")  # add a new mesh
obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyObject", mesh)  # add a new object using the mesh

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.objects.link(obj)  # put the object into the scene (link)
scene.objects.active = obj  # set as the active object in the scene
obj.select = True  # select object

mesh = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()

for v in verts:
    bm.verts.new(v)  # add a new vert

# make the bmesh the object's mesh
bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
bm.free()  # always do this when finished
```

This is how to alter an existing mesh:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

verts = [(1, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0)]  # 2 verts made with XYZ coords
mesh = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()

# convert the current mesh to a bmesh
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

for v in verts:
    bm.verts.new(v)  # add a new vert

# make the bmesh the object's mesh
bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
bm.free()  # always do this when finished
```

## Answer

As for selection:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

mesh = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.new()

# convert the current mesh to a bmesh
bm.from_mesh(mesh)

# must run this so we can use indexing on the faces
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

# "select" the 0th face by setting its select property to True
bm.faces[0].select = True

# make the bmesh the object's mesh
bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
bm.free()  # always do this when finished

# go back to edit mode to see the selection
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

To test this:

1. Add a cube (go into edit mode and deselect all faces)
2. Paste the script into Blender's text editor
3. Hit run script in the text editor with the cube object still selected

Comment: still it is not working?

Comment: Do ineed to download something else for bmesh?

Comment: Why are you toggling edit / object mode?  The mesh doesn't need to be in edit mode at all to use `bm.from_mesh()`.  To make it "live" in edit mode use `bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)` and `bmesh.update_edit_mesh(...)` to update changes to mesh without the need to toggle modes.

Comment: See my updated answer, and see if you are doing things the same as I am. @batFINGER Thanks, I updated my answer.

Comment: Don't you also need to specify which vertices are connected with edges?  Verts alone don't make a mesh!

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I assume you are talking about the first example? Verts alone actually do make a mesh (a non-manifold mesh, but still a mesh) because a mesh is just a data type in Blender (and many 3D software packages) to store vertices, edges, and faces. Although simply adding vertices will not make a *renderable* mesh, it is still a mesh nonetheless. The point was to give a few simple bmesh examples, but if you want an example of connecting the verts, let me know, and I would be happy to add it.